# Calculating the combined spam probability percentage using Naive Bayesian in php

Tags: php, algorithm, math, bayesian, spam-prevention

I'm currently developing a spam filter to detect forms used for phishing using the Bayesian spam filtering method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering.

It will work by scanning the text on the form and calculating a probability for each word to be spam and then combining these probabilities to calculate an overall % of the form being used for phishing.

Where I am failing is combining the individual probabilities to generate a the overall percentage. Also I've tested it on a larger forms and ended up with a resulting probability as a float in scientific notation with more than 10 places of zeroes. How can I turn these into a percentage? Maybe my implementation of the Bayesian method is incorrect?

Here is a code example from a large form:

```
//Probability of each word being on a phishing form
$words = array(
        'euro' => 0.36,
'million' => 0.57,
'international' => 0.33,
'award' => 0.23,
'europe' => 0.48,
'america' => 0.36,
'private' => 0.25,
'egames' => 0.90,
'organizers' => 0.08,
'cosponsors' => 0.69,
'officially' => 0.25,
'bring' => 0.16,
'your' => 0.38,
'notice' => 0.21,
'final' => 0.15,
'draw' => 0.40,
'result' => 0.16,
'egame' => 0.71,
'which' => 0.15,
'conducted' => 0.20,
'complex' => 0.06,
'corporate' => 0.14,
'office' => 0.14,
'spain' => 0.47,
'wish' => 0.15,
'congratulate' => 0.77,
'inform' => 0.24,
'selection' => 0.10,
'coupon' => 0.20,
'number' => 0.29,
'selected' => 0.21,
'among' => 0.27,
'lucky' => 0.70,
'consolation' => 0.36,
'prize' => 0.53,
'winners' => 0.24,
'identified' => 0.07,
'noemeggb' => 0.68,
'random' => 0.32,
'system' => 0.41,
'erss' => 0.68,
'entries' => 0.16,
'different' => 0.20,
'addresses' => 0.13,
'through' => 0.16,
'internet' => 0.36,
'included' => 0.06,
'submitted' => 0.14,
'partner' => 0.22,
'provider' => 0.17,
'companies' => 0.48,
'have' => 0.21,
'cash' => 0.54,
'eight' => 0.35,
'hundred' => 0.58,
'thousand' => 0.63,
'euros' => 0.52,
'only' => 0.25,
'approved' => 0.27,
'payout' => 0.49,
'renumerated' => 0.68,
'directly' => 0.16,
'official' => 0.27,
'payment' => 0.30,
'agency' => 0.39,
'board' => 0.13,
'process' => 0.20,
'unit' => 0.19,
'render' => 0.29,
'complete' => 0.23,
'assistance' => 0.20,
'provide' => 0.13,
'additional' => 0.11,
'information' => 0.25,
'processes' => 0.13,
'claims' => 0.12,
'consultation' => 0.07,
'validate' => 0.70,
'full' => 0.36,
'address' => 0.28,
'mobile' => 0.32,
'phone' => 0.27,
'date' => 0.41,
'birth' => 0.47,
'occupation' => 0.41,
'marital' => 0.36,
'status' => 0.32,
'enter' => 0.55,
'message' => 0.28,
'shown' => 0.44,
'choose' => 0.38,
'mode' => 0.28,
'received' => 0.16,
'winning' => 0.49,
'scanned' => 0.19,
'copy' => 0.29,
'passport' => 0.43,
'photograph' => 0.07,
'proof' => 0.23,
'reference' => 0.11,
'keyfrmadesp' => 0.68,
'batch' => 0.42,
'eumlserial' => 0.50,
'pmsq' => 0.68,
'ticket' => 0.26,
'nmky' => 0.68,
'nkky' => 0.68,
'assured' => 0.12,
'utmost' => 0.10,
'standards' => 0.11,
'confidentiality' => 0.15,
'press' => 0.19,
'anonymity' => 0.54,
'until' => 0.22,
'proceedings' => 0.07,
'yours' => 0.31,
'faithfully' => 0.41,
'gomez' => 0.56,
'zonal' => 0.69,
'coordinator' => 0.09,
'claim' => 0.47,
'agent' => 0.41,
'officer' => 0.22,
    );


//Combine the word probabilities
$p = 1;
$sum = 1;
foreach ($words as $word => $score) {

    $p *= $score;

    $sum *= (1 - $score);
}

$probability = $p / ($p + $sum);

Probability form is spam = float(1.4948061676356E-46)
```

So have I calculated this correctly? Should the probability really have that many places of zeros? And how can I turn this number into a percentage that the form is used for phishing?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you should ask such questions on stats.stackexchange.com they do statistics there

Comment: Shouldn't you test the algorithm on a real message and not on the keyword list? After all, many of your probabilities are smaller than 0.5. So it's no surprise that you get a very small probability.

Comment: @NicoSchertler The keyword list is generated by parsing a form and then calculating the probability of spam for each word based on previous results